# BI mondrian schema

Tags: mdx, pentaho, business-intelligence, mondrian

I have a cube with some calculated members. What I want to do is to use a calculated member in the formula of another calculated member. I have try with the following but no help ... I got errors when loading the schema:

```
<CalculatedMember name="M1" description="Unit: NA. Aggregation: Avg. Validation: none" formula="[Measures].[M]*1.9" dimension="Measures" >
        <CalculatedMemberProperty name="FORMAT_STRING" value="#0.00">
        </CalculatedMemberProperty> 
    </CalculatedMember>
    <CalculatedMember name="M2" description="Unit: NA" formula="[Measures].[M1]*1000" dimension="Measures" >
      <CalculatedMemberProperty name="FORMAT_STRING" value="#0.00">
      </CalculatedMemberProperty> 
    </CalculatedMember>
```

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works well Pentaho Analyzer 5.1.  Your syntax for the calculated members is correct.

Check if the Measure "M" exists? For example:

```
<Measure name="M" column="TOTALPRICE" aggregator="sum" visible="true">
</Measure>
```

If it exists, give more details: Error Message, Tool, Version?

Comment: Thank you! There was a problem with my measure!